# Bug or feature? Sudden wrapping of lines when window width increases

Tags: wrapping

**Context**: *GNU Emacs 29.0.60 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2023-03-30, Development version 4508a024e818 on emacs-29 branch; build date 2023-03-30. Linux Mint 21 (Vanessa) Cinnamon: ~ $ emacs -Q .*

How to reproduce the in the image shown behavior?

1. Start Emacs with ~ $ emacs -Q
2. Split the window into 3 parts
3. Show window divider
4. Play around with the width of the windows

---

In the image below captured what shouldn't be able to exist: three windows showing the same buffer, with Line Wrapping set to the default value of "Truncate Long Lines":

[image]

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html

Comment: @Shynur : may you please explain what does the term "split window" mentioned in the linked documentation, mean? This term seem not to be explained also in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior, controlled by the value of `truncate-partial-width-windows`.  See its doc string for the details.

Comment: To disable the wrapping no matter the window width I set the value to `t` (correct?) . The help text about this value is expressed in an for me not easy to understand way, so I was forced to find it out by trial-and-error. First, after reading the help, I have thought I should set it to nil, but setting it to nil causes line wrapping in any of the multiple windows.

Comment: ... and welcome to emacs.stackexchange.com . I am very happy to see you being here.

Comment: @Claudio: Which part of the doc string do you find confusing? (Seems pretty clear to me.) If you have a suggestion for improvement or can point out a problem (e.g. ambiguity), maybe file an enhancement request, with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew: in order to make really good enhancements it would be first necessary to get a deep understanding of what is going on behind the curtains and how all the used terms are defined. I am still in the process of getting out of confusion gaining more clarity and I am wondering how it comes that you are not confused yourself reading the documentation. Are you able to see from the text that you have to set the value to t in order to switch the wrapping off? And if yes, how do you conclude it from the text?

Comment: @Claudio: From the doc string: (1) I'm guessing that your middle "window width in column units is *not* less than" 50 (default), so that window's text isn't truncated. (2) "Any other non-nil value" (e.g. `t`) truncates lines in all windows that do not span the full frame width."

Comment: @Claudio: To be helpful you need not necessarily have a deep understanding of what happens and why. It can sometimes help just to point out some particular text you see that confused you, or that you didn't understand. Just signaling that something is unclear to you might help others. And if not, that'll be politely pointed out to you, with a "thank you" for your report. Feedback is important for improvement, even feedback that doesn't come from "a deep understanding of what is going on behind the curtains" etc. The doc aims to help even people who aren't experts.

Comment: @Drew: let's start with the very simple case of the term "split window" mentioned in the documentation linked by *Shynur* in the comment to my question. This term is used, but not explained. Neither where it is mentioned, nor in the documentation for splitting windows.

Comment: @Drew : a very complex case is a problem with the phrase: "lines in all windows that do not span the full frame width" which you consider understandable. What does "full frame width" mean in this phrase? What does the term "frame" mean at all in Emacs??? And what "do not span the full width"? The lines? Or the windows?

Comment: @Drew : https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html citation : "A frame is a rectangular cluster of Emacs windows." does not cover the case of GUI interface having a "Title-Bar with [-] [+] [x] buttons", "Menu-Bar with the Menu", "Toolbar", modeline, "Scrollbars". This definition can't be right, because if I create a new frame ( https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Creating-Frames.html ) I will get beside the "cluster of Emacs windows" many other things.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. This is not a discussion site. Comments aren't searchable and can be deleted at any time. Put all relevant info in Q & A. Thx.